# How to develop self contained android applications using Julia?

Tags: android, julia

I would like to develop android applications in julia.  But, couldn't find good resources/arcles in this regard by googling.

Any guidance on writing self contained android application in julia would be highly appreciated!

Update1:

It is understood that:

Mr.Nathan Daly has developed self contained Julia application for iOS(Reference: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/building-and-releasing-a-fully-self-contained-application-written-in-julia/10418).

Java with AWT, SQLite and web-services are used in mobile development.

In the similar lines, please guide me in developing android application in julia with Gtk or some other package(s), SQLite and web-services!